# Prolog: No permission to redefine imported_procedure error

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am actualy working on a university project and I'm having troubles with some predicates.
The project concerns the recreation of the Dijkstra's algorithm with some predicates that my professor gave me to write.

As the title says, I keep getting the error

> **No permission to redifine imported_procedure**

with the predicates ***vertices/2*** and ***neighbors/3*** form the library `ugraphs` and with the predicate ***heap_size/2*** from `heaps`.

Here's how i made them up:

```
vertices(G, Vs) :-
   findall(V, vertex(G, V), Vs).

neighbors(G, V, Ns) :-
   findall(arc(G, V, N, W), arc(G, V, N, W), Ns1),
   findall(arc(G, N, V, W), arc(G, N, V, W), Ns2),
   append(Ns1, Ns2, Ns).

heap_dim(H, S) :-
   heap(H, S).
```

I already tried to set them all ***:-dynamic*** but nothing had change (well, something had change: i was getting even the error : **dynamic/1: No permission to redifine imported_procedure**).

So, what's the problem? Why does the listener keep calling those libraries even if I don't want him to? How could I solve it?

I already thought about changing their names but I can't just because my professor wants me to create them as so.

Here's the link with the project if you want to give it a try:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zRmoBDdWJkjlWzQbFs_g6sQBhRF0joaM/view?usp=sharing

If you run `?- shortest_path(G, A, B, Path).`, the listener says what's the shortest Path from the point A to point B in the graph G (if you want to give it a try run `test_2(G).` before running `shortest_path(G, Source, V, Path).`).

All Dijkstra's algorithm it's made up by using heap structure

Thanks for all!

EDIT: there it is the  [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcfBA.png) about Prolog's listener when i'm trying to compile the program

and the exact source file I'm running is the one linked above: on emacs I open the file that is actually located at path you see in the image

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what Prolog you are using, and could you post a *short, self-contained, complete* example program? On my SWI-Prolog 7.6.4, if I `:- use_module(library(ugraphs))` and then try to define a `vertices/2` predicate, I get a warning about the redefinition. If I don't use the module, there is no problem. Do you want to use this module? If yes, you might want to give your own predicates different names. SWI also has a variant of `use_module` that allows you to rename imported predicates to avoid a name clash.

Comment: I'm actually working on SWI-Prolog 8.2.1.

I've already tried to use different names and everything worked. 
The only problem is that I have to use them because it's what the professor wants.
I also tried modules like you said, but I rather prefer not using them just because we didn't see them at lesson (like modules, i didn't use `not` or `or` in the program just for this reason). Is there a way to solve this problem without using them?

And last, I didn't get what you meant with _could you post a short, self-contained, complete example program?_

Comment: I think you'll have to ask your professor for guidance. Like me, they might be using an older version of SWI-Prolog that is less strict about this issue. They might not be aware that newer versions have this error message. Your professor will have to decide whether to use the module system properly. I don't think there is another solution.

Comment: See: [https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/no-permission-to-redefine-imported-procedure-error/2892](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/no-permission-to-redefine-imported-procedure-error/2892)

Comment: Fun fact: that's still me asking to Prolog's Developers. I tried to follow his suggestions but I didn't manage to find a solution. I look at the modules documentations and tried to implement it but, I don't know what I did, I actually manage to broke down the first program i wrote. So, this is why I also don't want to use modules again :)

Comment: I've now tested this on version 7.6.4, 8.0.0, and 8.2.1. I cannot reproduce this. Please edit your post to include the **exact** source file you use (please make it at most five lines), also show us the **exact** command line you use to run SWI-Prolog.

Comment: I've posted a screen of the listener. Sorry again, I didn't get what you meant with _include the exact source file you use (please make it at most five lines)_